# ajax unknown server tag asp scriptmanager

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have this in my Register

`<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>`

But when I drop and drag a scriptmanager into VS2010 i receieve the error ajax unknown server tag asp scriptmanager

`<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />`

changed it to

`<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>`

Still produces the error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tagprefix in your @register and the tag in in front of the scriptmanager must match. Also I think you better use the ToolkitScriptManager that comes with the toolkit http://blog.turlov.com/2008/05/scriptmanager-vs-toolkitscriptmanager.html:

In my case it is cc1:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```

and in your  `<body>`

```
<cc1:ToolkitScriptManager ID="TKSM" EnablePageMethods="true" EnableCdn="true" ScriptMode="Release" runat="server">
</cc1:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

Comment: I dont have ToolkitScriptManager in my toolbox, why is that?

Answer (score 11):

In your system.web you need to add:

```
<pages>
      <controls>
               <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=1.0.61025.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
      </controls>
  </pages>
```

Comment: i just saw that and changed it to, '<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" %>'  However, this still produces the same error.

Comment: I added the script manager under my Ajax Extensions in my VS2010, does that help any?

Comment: Oskar, i must be on the same path you are, i added that to my web.config and then i got this in return `The type or namespace name 'ScriptManager' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?` so then i added System.Web.Extensions and still got the error http://forums.asp.net/t/1070186.aspx/1?The+type+or+namespace+name+ScriptManager+does+not+exist+in+the+namespace+System+Web+UI+are+you+missing+an+assembly+reference+

Comment: great did all of that and now Ajax disappeared from my toolbox

Comment: it still doesn't fix the problem

Comment: why when i automatically add Ajax to the site do i ge tthe prefix of TagPrefix="asp"

Answer (score 3):

Add  targetFramework="4.0" in the compilation tag in web.config file.

Answer (score 0):

just Try this:
Add this code in your web.config file

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

OR

Rebuild your project

Comment: OR? Did you just suggest he rebuilds his solution to fix the problem?